# Project compiling with raylib static library

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I am trying to create a game with the Raylib library. I just was until now just trying around inside the `main.cpp` and always compiled my code with this line inside the terminal.

```
clang -std=c++11 -framework CoreVideo -framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL  libraylib.a main.cpp -o my_app
```

Now I want to recreate the Snake game just for fun. I thought I would be wise the spilt the main.cpp into multiple src files but I actually don't know how I should compile all of this. I tried to create a CMakeList.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework CoreVideo")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework IOKit")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework Cocoa")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework GLUT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework OpenGL")

project(Snake)

add_executable(
    Snake
    main.cpp
    Snake.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/librarylib.a)
```

but this doesn't work. This is the Error message.

```
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this
  project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Are there better ways to compile this project and can anyone explain to me what the `-framework` flag actually does?  I still want to use VSCode because I want to learn how to use the terminal a bit better.

Edit: Information form `brew ls --verbose raylib`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/LICENSE.md
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/.brew/raylib.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/CHANGELOG
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/include/raylib.h
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/HISTORY.md
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/README.md
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/pkgconfig/raylib.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/cmake/raylib/raylib-config-version.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/cmake/raylib/raylib-config.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/libraylib.2.5.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/libraylib.2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/libraylib.a
/usr/local/Cellar/raylib/2.5.0/lib/libraylib.dylib
```

Comment: If you run `brew ls --verbose raylib` it will tell you where the header and library files are, and also where the **CMake** and **pkgconfig** file `"raylib.pc"` are located. Then click `edit` under your question, paste that information in and some helpful soul should be able to tell you how to tell that stuff to **CMake**.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added the Information!

Comment: I'm not good on `cmake` but I think you just need `include("/usr/local/Cellar....raylib-config.cmake")`

Comment: Alright! I will try that if I get home. I will tell you the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by setting my `CMakeLists.txt` up like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Snake)


set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
# Executable & linking
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp snake.cpp)
if (NOT TARGET raylib)
  find_package(raylib 2.5.0 REQUIRED)
endif()
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} raylib)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to link your executable to `librarylib.a`. The target name of your executable is `Snake`.

If we look at the error:

> Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this project.

Indeed, you never added a library or an executable called `main`.

This is what should be in your `target_link_libraries` call should look like:

```
target_link_libraries(Snake PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/librarylib.a")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was one Error as it seems, but I installed the Raylib with brew and now CMake doesnt find the `#include "raylib.h"`. How do I fix this?